# scala early initializer with var cause ClassCastException

Tags: scala

I tried the following code:

```
class C(val g: Int => Int)
object C {
    object A extends {
        var f: Int => Int = x => x
    } with C(x => f(x) + 1)

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(A.g(3))
    }
}
```

It can compile (at scala version 2.12.2), but throws Exception at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at pkg1.C$.main(C.scala:14)
  at pkg1.C.main(C.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.ObjectRef cannot be cast to scala.Function1
  at pkg1.C$A$.<init>(C.scala:10)
  at pkg1.C$A$.<clinit>(C.scala)
  ... 2 more
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you sure your code compiles? I can't compile it with scala 2.11.8. It fails with `scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: type mismatch; found   : runtime.ObjectRef; required: Function1`

Comment: I think the code does not compiles

Comment: I am using scala version 2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a scalac bug (/unintended interference of features of early initialization of variables and lambda type references' class type) caused by using method handles for functions starting from [2.12](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0):

> Scala and Java 8 interop is also improved for functional code, as methods that take functions can easily be called in both directions using lambda syntax. The `FunctionN` classes in Scala’s standard library are now Single Abstract Method (SAM) types, and all [SAM types](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types) are treated uniformly – from type checking through code generation. No class file is generated for a lambda; `invokedynamic` is used instead.

Edit: I could not find a good workaround for this problem besides changing the `var` to `val`, but I guess that is not possible in your use case.